# Number of way to select N rocks from two different bins

Tags: combinatorics

There are two bins, one is red, and there are $M$ rocks in it.

The other bin is green, and there are $N$ rocks in it.

We will choose $K$ rocks from these two bins, and with a limitation: $K \le M+N$

My question, the number of choose way.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  you will choose $p$ rocks from the red bin and (how many?) rocks from the green bin. If I told you $p$, can you give the answer?  But you are not given $p$, so you need to sum over the allowable values.  What are the limits?

Comment: Choose $K$ rocks totally. If choose $p$ rocks ( where $p$ less or equal than $K$)from the red bin, then choose $K-p$ rocks from the green bin.

Comment: So should I sum over all the allowable values? If the number of allowable values is too big, I think I can't finish it.

Comment: Yes, you should sum over the allowable values of $p$.  It can't be larger than $K$, nor $M$, nor smaller than (what?).  As you add conditions to combinatoric problems, it is easy to make the calculations a mess.  If $K$ is close to $M$ or $N$ you get a minimum number of rocks taken from the other bin.  That may help, or not.